# Dimension mismatch in Keras sequence to sequence model with Attention

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a Neural Machine Translation model with `attention`. I am following the tutorial on [Keras blog](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/nlp/lstm_seq2seq.py) that shows how to build a NMT model using sequence-to-sequence approach (without attention). I extended the model to incorporate `attention`  in the following way -

```
latent_dim = 300
embedding_dim=100
batch_size  = 128

# Encoder
encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))


#encoder lstm 1
encoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(latent_dim,return_sequences=True,return_state=True,dropout=0.4,recurrent_dropout=0.4)
encoder_output, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_inputs)
print(encoder_output.shape)

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, num_decoder_tokens))


decoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True,dropout=0.4,recurrent_dropout=0.2)
decoder_output,decoder_fwd_state, decoder_back_state = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs,initial_state=[state_h, state_c])

# Attention layer
attn_out = tf.keras.layers.Attention()([encoder_output, decoder_output])

# Concat attention input and decoder LSTM output
decoder_concat_input = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat_layer')([decoder_output, attn_out])

#dense layer
decoder_dense =  tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax'))
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_concat_input)

# Define the model 
attn_model = tf.keras.Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

attn_model.summary()
```

To train the model -

```
attn_model.compile(
    optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
)

history = attn_model.fit(
    [encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data],
    decoder_target_data,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=5,
    validation_split=0.2,
)
```

Here I have below shape

`encoder_input_data.shape` is `(10000, 16, 71)`

`decoder_input_data.shape` is `(10000, 59, 92)`

`decoder_target_data.shape` is `(10000, 59, 92)`

When I train this model, I get below error:
`InvalidArgumentError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 59 and 16. Shapes are [?,59] and [?,16]. for 'model/concat_layer/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [?,59,300], [?,16,300], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <2>.`

I understand that it is complaining about the dimension of `encoder_input_data` and `decoder_input_data` but this same setup works when we run the regular sequence-to-sequence model (without attention) as discussed in [keras blog](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/nlp/lstm_seq2seq.py).In this case, it is throwing error because of the `Concatenation` layer.

Can anyone please suggest how to fix this?